# Fluent-bit in Kubernetes cannot input timestamp data properly

Tags: logging, kubernetes, elasticsearch, fluentd

At my company, I built a K8s cluster with Terraform and configured a logging system with EFK (Elasticsearch, Fluent-bit, Kibana).

k8s and Elasticsearch use AWS's EKS and Opensearch Servcie (ES 7.10), and Fluent-bit was installed separately as a Daemonset through Helm.

https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/fluent/fluent-bit

In the case of Fluent-bit Config, it is structured as follows.

```
config:
   inputs: |
     [INPUT]
         Name tail
         Exclude_Path /var/log/containers/cloudwatch-agent*, /var/log/containers/fluent-bit*, /var/log/containers/aws-node*, /var/log/containers/kube-proxy*, / var/log/containers/aws-load-balancer*, /var/log/containers/cert-manager*, /var/log/containers/coredns*, /var/log/containers/ebs-csi*, /var/ log/containers/grafana*, /var/log/containers/karpenter*, /var/log/containers/metrics-server*, /var/log/containers/prometheus*
         Path /var/log/containers/*.log
         Tag kube.*
         Mem_Buf_Limit 50MB
         multiline.parser python-custom

   outputs: |
     [OUTPUT]
         Name es
         Match kube.*
         Host ${es_domain_name}
         Port 443
         TLS On
         AWS_Auth On
         AWS_Region ${region}
         Retry_Limit 6
         Replace_Dots On
         Trace_Error On

   filters: |
     [FILTER]
         Name kubernetes
         Match kube.*
         Merge_Log On
         Merge_Log_Key log_processed
         Keep_LogOff
         K8S-Logging.Parser On
         K8S-Logging.Exclude On

   customParsers: |
     [MULTILINE_PARSER]
         name python-custom
         type regex
         flush_timeout 1000
         rule "start_state" "/stderr F(.*)/" "cont"
         rule "cont" "/stderr F(.*)/" "cont"
```

Overall it worked fine, but one day, after a certain situation, I noticed that all the logs collected by Fluent-bit were all pointing to the same timestamp.

Previously, the log output from the Pod was recorded with an accurate timestamp, but after the Pod is reloaded, the log continues to be recorded with a fixed @timestamp, and since logs are accumulated in the past time zone, the following phenomenon appears when viewed in kibana.

Logs are all transmitted to ES in real time, but since they are all collected at a fixed past time, proper queries cannot be executed.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ue6qU.png)

```
// Unlike the timestamp output in the actual application, the timestamp recorded in Fluent-bit remains the same.
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:48:55...[2023-10-16 09:48:55]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:48:55...[2023-10-16 09:48:55]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:53:55...[2023-10-16 09:53:55]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:58:03...[2023-10-16 09:58:03]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:58:03...[2023-10-16 09:58:03]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:58:03...[2023-10-16 09:58:03]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:58:55...[2023-10-16 09:58:55]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T09:58:55...[2023-10-16 09:58:55]... 
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T10:03:03...[2023-10-16 10:03:03]...
Oct 16, 2023 @ 16:13:36.142 2023-10-16T10:03:55...[2023-10-16 10:03:55]...
```

This problem occurs when updating and reloading Pods running for each service. I confirmed that the inotify_fs_add log was output to Fluent-bit for the newly created Pod, and no other error logs could be confirmed.

#### Pod Reloading

```
│ backend-api-deployment-5d9fc55496-8mppx                            ●  1/1          0 Running
│ backend-api-deployment-57d68dd4f5-djn8x                            ●  1/1          0 Terminating
```

#### Fluent-bit Log

```
│ Fluent Bit v2.1.8
│ * Copyright (C) 2015-2022 The Fluent Bit Authors
│ * Fluent Bit is a CNCF sub-project under the umbrella of Fluentd
│ * https://fluentbit.io
│
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [fluent bit] version=2.1.8, commit=1d83649441, pid=1
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [storage] ver=1.4.0, type=memory, sync=normal, checksum=off, max_chunks_up=128
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [cmetrics] version=0.6.3
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [ctraces ] version=0.3.1
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] initializing
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] storage_strategy='memory' (memory only)
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] multiline core started
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] https=1 host=kubernetes.default.svc port=443
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0]  token updated
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] local POD info OK
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] testing connectivity with API server...
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0] connectivity OK
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [output:es:es.0] worker #0 started
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [output:es:es.0] worker #1 started
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [http_server] listen iface=0.0.0.0 tcp_port=2020
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [sp] stream processor started
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_add(): inode=41916664 watch_fd=1 name=/var/log/containers/backend-api-deployment-57d68dd4f5-djn8x_backend-dev_backend-api-f950104ab9f300586803316ad7beef5c9506db9fceeb4af0dc0575b3b9bacfd7.log
│ [2023/10/16 16:05:00] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_add(): inode=17488499 watch_fd=2 name=/var/log/containers/backend-api-deployment-6dc5b97645-tqwxh_backend-staging_backend-api-23f14f74af6cc163f233499ba92a2746cb2f263c9379ba53fc47cd3d76e00bbb.log
...
│ [2023/10/17 04:49:01] [error] [output:es:es.0] HTTP status=429 URI=/_bulk, response:
│ 429 Too Many Requests /_bulk
│
│ [2023/10/17 04:49:01] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1697518140.870529031.flb', retry in 6 seconds: task_id=1, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
│ [2023/10/17 04:49:01] [error] [output:es:es.0] HTTP status=429 URI=/_bulk, response:
│ 429 Too Many Requests /_bulk
│
│ [2023/10/17 04:49:01] [ warn] [engine] failed to flush chunk '1-1697518140.276173730.flb', retry in 7 seconds: task_id=0, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
│ [2023/10/17 04:49:07] [ info] [engine] flush chunk '1-1697518140.870529031.flb' succeeded at retry 1: task_id=1, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
│ [2023/10/17 04:49:08] [ info] [engine] flush chunk '1-1697518140.276173730.flb' succeeded at retry 1: task_id=0, input=tail.0 > output=es.0 (out_id=0)
│ [2023/10/17 05:08:50] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_add(): inode=37547666 watch_fd=8 name=/var/log/containers/backend-api-deployment-5d9fc55496-8mppx_backend-dev_backend-api-839c128d6227f797722496a992ca9149b95c366997c2b1ec28ceb65490582e3b.log
│ [2023/10/17 05:08:52] [ info] [filter:kubernetes:kubernetes.0]  token updated
│ [2023/10/17 05:09:25] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_remove(): inode=41916664 watch_fd=1
│ [2023/10/17 05:09:37] [ info] [input:tail:tail.0] inotify_fs_remove(): inode=17488499 watch_fd=2
```

What's interesting is that **if all fluent-bit Daemon Sets are manually killed and revived through self-healing,** they will all temporarily be collected normally again.

After that, if you update and reload the Service Pod again, the same problem occurs again.

What causes this problem? How can I fix it? And if there are any recommended Fluent-bit settings, additional advice is welcome.

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a clear cause, but I think I found a solution, so I'm sharing it with you.

When checking the log in Kibana, various timestamps are recorded, but as you can see in the attached image, there is a problem with the timestamp recorded directly by Fluent-bit.

However, considering that once Fluent-bit reboots the Pod, everything returns to normal, it is difficult to think that my Config is wrong.

So, I considered parsing the time information from my Application Log, which continues to output the normal time, and specifying the time directly instead of using the default `@timestamp` recorded by Fluent-bit.

I declared a parser as shown below, extracted the value from the string in the log using a regular expression that parses time information, and then applied it using `Time_Key`.

```
[PARSER] 
        Name log_timestamp
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<log_time>[^\s]+)
        Time_Key log_time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
        Time_Keep On
```

The above Parser was operated using the parser filter in the Filter Pipeline.

```
    [FILTER]
        Name parser
        Match kube.*
        Key_Name log
        Parser log_timestamp 
        Preserve_Key On
        Reserve_Data On
```

In other words, Full Configure is as follows.

```
config:
  inputs: |
    [INPUT]
        Name tail
        Path /var/log/containers/*.log
        Tag kube.*
        Mem_Buf_Limit 50MB
        Refresh_Interval 10
        multiline.parser python-custom

  outputs: |
    [OUTPUT]
        Name            es
        Match           kube.*
        Host            ${es_domain_name}
        Port            443
        TLS             On
        AWS_Auth        On
        AWS_Region      ${region}
        Retry_Limit     6
        Replace_Dots    On
        Trace_Error     On    

  filters: |
    [FILTER]
        Name kubernetes
        Match kube.*
        Merge_Log On
        Merge_Log_Key       log_processed
        Keep_Log Off
        K8S-Logging.Parser On
        K8S-Logging.Exclude On
    
    [FILTER]
        Name parser
        Match kube.*
        Key_Name log
        Parser log_timestamp 
        Preserve_Key On
        Reserve_Data On

  customParsers: |
    [MULTILINE_PARSER]
        name          python-custom
        type          regex
        flush_timeout 1000
        rule      "start_state"   "/stderr F(.*)/"  "cont"
        rule      "cont"          "/stderr F(.*)/"  "cont"
    
    [PARSER] 
        Name log_timestamp
        Format regex
        Regex ^(?<log_time>[^\s]+)
        Time_Key log_time
        Time_Format %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%LZ
        Time_Keep On
```